# How to plot barchart with errorbars when standard deviation is more than mean in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Suppose I have three randomly generated normal distribution data of the form:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])
```

I have to plot barcharts with errorbars at 95% confidence interval, so I use the following code:

```
Mean = df.mean(axis=1)
STD = df.std(axis=1)
Year = df.index.tolist()
x_pos = np.arange(len(Year))
fig, axs = plt.subplots()
axs.bar(x_pos, Mean, yerr=2*STD, width=0.3, align='center',
        alpha=0.5, ecolor='black', capsize=10)
axs.set_xticks(x_pos)
axs.set_xticklabels(Year)
```

But, I get the following graph:

[image: I get the following graph]

How can I have the bars till the bottom ?

Comment: You could add a horizontal line at `y=0`:  `axs.axhline(0)`.  Or you could add a bottom to the barplot (default is 0), `axs.bar(...., bottom=-400000, ....)`

Comment: I tried adding bottom to the barplot, but that just takes mean = -400000+mean value not the actual mean value. Any other way ?

Comment: So, what is it you really want? Your values can have a very large range, from about -700000 to +700000. Would drawing a horizontal axis at `y=0` work for you? Representing the mean as a bar probably doesn't give a good visualization of the distribution. What about seaborn's `sns.violinplot(data=df.T)` or `sns.stripplot(data=df.T)`?

Comment: Yeah, I am completing a course so not have got to seaborn part, I will look into it.Thanks